# When to clean trailing/leading whitespace from user input - On Input or Before DB Insertion?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, forms, model-view-controller

I've got a question which would be applicable to an MVC based platform, but I guess also applicable to any web based platform which handles user form inputs.

What are the best practices, and ideal stage from which to remove trailing/leading whitespace from user input?

I see this could happen at a few stages:

1. **Immediately Upon User Form Input** - ala Javascript functions to strip as they type/pre-submission
2. **Inside the Controller on Params Submission**
3. **Intermediate Model/Attribute Methods**
4. **Prior to or upon Database Persistence**

***What is best practice in this regard, and specifically the pro's/con's for doing it at a certain stage, or multiple?***)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the type of application:

- For a standard web app, I would say you definitely want to clean data on the browser sometime before submission so that you can validate it (for ex. an email would fail validation if it has a leading space or a length check). It is better to validate without sending data to the server when possible.
- If you are writing an API, especially a public one, I would definitely clean the data server side or return an error. You can't trust clients to send you clean data. I would probably do it in the model before validation which shouldn't be to hard to do automatically.
- If bad data can cause a security issue (XSS or SQL injection) then you want to clean it on the server as well as the client. Even on a web app there is nothing stopping a malicious user faking a request from a web browser. If spaces in the data won't break anything then this may not be necessary (if someone 'maliciously' adds a leading space to their blog title it might look weird but it is only going to harm them)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinion based question I think. It would depends on the persons who is implementing and also the application.
If you don't have to clean immediately after user input, I would say avoid `#1` since it will be confusing to your users while they are typing, and also it can have a performance impact on slower/smaller devices.
`#2` and `#3` will both be very similar, a nice thing about `#3` is that if you're using the same property in many places, your logic for trimming will live in only one place, but both will run on your server which takes away the perf hit from client device.

`#4` depending on your DBMS can be very easy or difficult to implement.

I would personally choose `#2` or `#3`, but again that's my opinion and someone else can have a completely different one than mine.

Also you certainly don't need to do it multiple if you get one stage right.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I didn't want this to be opinion based, which is why I asked specifically what the pro's/con's were for each stage to keep it objective, and allow anyone to make a fair evaluation based on their own priorities. That said, you raised some good points, thanks!